# karplus equation in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, equation

I want plot karplus equation

```
f(t)=a*cos(t+o)**2 + b*cos(t+o) + c
```

with gnuplot for different value of a, b, c, o values. In particular the parameters a, b, c, o have tabular form (in file data.dat):

```
a b c o
1 2 3 60
4 5 6 180
-3 -5 -9 -120
```

and t has range from

```
-180 to 180
```

for each row in data.dat file.

Can you help me? Thanks everyone.

Lucio

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it is not possible to have a "parameter file" with different parameters to plot in a function since the plot command can **either** take a function to plot **or** a datafile:

```
plot {<ranges>}
     {<iteration>}
     {<function> | {"<datafile>" {datafile-modifiers}}}
     {axes <axes>} {<title-spec>} {with <style>}
     {, {definitions{,}} <function> ...}
```

So either you have to create a datafile where your `t` and functional values are listed for gnuplot to plot. An other workaround, that might be useful if you only have a limited number of karplus functions to plot is this:

```
set angles degrees
set xrange [-180:180]

f(x, a, b, c, o) = a*cos(x+o)**2 + b*cos(x+o) + c
title(n) = sprintf("f_%d", n)

plot a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 o = 60 f(x, a, b, c, o) t title(1), \
     a = 4 b = 5 c = 6 o = 180 f(x, a, b, c, o) t title(2), \
     a = -3 b = -5 c = -9 o = -120 f(x, a, b, c, o) t title(3)
```

Now you specify the parameters directly and and plot the function accordingly.

Alternatively you could implement an iteration like so:

```
plot for [a = 1:10:2] b = 2 c = 3 o = 60 f(x, a, b, c, o) t title(a)
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to nest iterations in gnuplot, so you have to cope with just having one parameter to vary.

Answer (score 1):

If your first column was "t" (and "a" was your second column etc.), you could do:

```
plot "data.dat" u 1:($2*cos($1+$5)+$3*cos($1+$5)+$4)
```

Note the parens on the outside of what comes after the colon.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution should work fine but there is a problem with t, $1, because I can't specify it in data.dat and its range is [-180:180]. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Do you want separate plots for each line of data.dat, or all of the karplus functions plotted together on one set of axes?

Comment: My idea is to plot each line of data.dat like a separate plot, but finally superimpose them in an unique plot

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, as far as I know. What I do in this sort of case is to write a small script to generate the plot commands I need. For example, using `awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env awk -f 

BEGIN {
    printf("plot ")
}

NR > 1 {
    printf(" ,\\\n     ")
}

{ 
    printf("(%s) * cos(t+(%s))**2 + (%s) * cos(t+(%s)) + (%s)", $1, $4, $2, $4, $3)  
}

END {
    printf("\n")
}
```

Save that as a file `karplus` and make it executable. Then `./karplus < data.dat` creates the plot command you need. Depending on your needs, a small makefile might be in order.