# How to do a parameter variation with gnuplot?

Tags: parameters, gnuplot

I want to plot a function like `f(x)=a*x^2+b*x+c` several times using `gnuplot` - each time with a different set of parameters. The parameters are stored in a csv file.

How could I do that?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6284170/572616) question.

Answer (score 0):

try this in *gnuplot* :

`f(x, a, b, c) = a*x**2 + b*x + c`

`plot f(x,1,1,1) , f(x,3,2,3) , f(x,1,0,0)`